# K-fold cross validation: confusion over which model is actually chosen and validated

Tags: cross-validation, resampling

I am watching the online lectures of Machine Learning by Hastie and Tibshirani, which are quite good. But they discussed $k$-fold cross-validation and there is something confusing me. As they describe it, the analyst will divide the dataset into $k$ equal partitions and then use $k-1$ partitions to train the model. Once the model is trained, the system will capture the mean squared error for the model applied to the $k$th partition that was used as a testing set. The analyst repeats this process for each of the $k$ folks, whether that be 5 or 10, etc.

Now, in one of their quiz questions--image below--they suggest that in each folk of the cross-validation, the model is retrained or refit to the data. So you may actually have different predictors in the model from one fold to another. Different predictors means a different model, right. But even if the predictors are the same from fold to fold, you are almost certain to get different coefficients on the predictors from fold to folks, so again the models will be different. 
[image]
So my question is what are we doing when we cross-validate? If the model keeps changing from one fold to the next--which may not happen often but can--then will cross-validation tell us how a particular model performs against test data? No, since we are testing multiple different models. Are we just supposed to pick the model that performs the best out of all the k-folds and test it against all folds again?

Again, just wanted to clarify how is k-fold cross validation supposed to work if the models change from fold to fold.

Comment: Yes, we will pick the model that performs better "on average". Consider two competing multivariate linear regression models with 3 or 4 predictors and $k$-fold CV scheme with $k=2$. We fit our 3-predictor model with on fold $1$ and we test it on fold $2$, error is $100$. We fit our 3-predicor model on fold $2$ test on fold $1$ and errors is $110$. Average CV error for the 3-predictor model is $105$. We can repeat the same process for the 4-predictor model and get test error for fold $1$, $80$ and for fold $2$, $120$, ie. average error 100. We choose the 4-predictor model. (cont.)

Comment: @usεr11852 okay, so this makes sense. So just to clarify, if we pick the 4 predictor model, then which set of coefficients do we pick for the 4 parameter model. Do we pick the set of coefficients or $\beta$s from fold 1 since it was the lowest error at 80. Or do we average the coefficient values for fold 1 and 2 of the 4 parameter model? There is a central limit theorem argument here, but the small number of folds mean small sample problem. Was not sure what guarantees exist.

Comment: All resampling schemes have some inherit variability. Through $k$-fold or bootstrapping our goodness-of-fit metric we are trying to get some estimator about its overall behaviour. That estimator will have some variance (and bias) due to finite sample size being used, due to the underlying modelling procedure being variable itself but also due to the sampling scheme we use.

Comment: Why would we limit ourselves? We would fit a final model using folds $1$ and $2$ together. That way our final model's $\hat{\beta}$ will reflect the overall behaviour of the sample more closely.

Comment: Okay, so once we know which model is best--the 4 predictor model--then we can fit over the entire dataset again?

Comment: Yes, we do. (extra characters to get the limit)

Comment: Phew, thanks so much for clarifying. This makes sense. I was getting answers all over the place.

Comment: Check Kuhn and Johnson's "*Applied Predictive Modelling*", Chapt. 4. Section 4.6 "*Choosing Final Tuning Parameters*" is exactly about this.